# Reading File in Java and memorize bytes where it stops

Tags: java, file, byte

i've to read in a .txt file. That File contains 13 parameters seperated by ",". I read it line by line, split after "," and wrote those 13 parameters in a database. But theres one Problem :

That file gets a bit bigger everyday (~ 2mb), so reading it by line will soon take a lot of time. So i thought of the following:

I want to read the file, then memorize the amount of bytes where the file finishes, write this "pointer" in a database and then next time start reading AFTER that bytes where the pointer is pointing to. (This way i don't have to read the whole stuff i already have again).

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using BufferedReader to read a file line by line?

Comment: Yes, I'm using BufferedReader.

Comment: If you are reading a file in this way then I doubt if you can skip certain bytes to continue reading again. I had a similar requirement a couple of years back (to read incremental log file) and have posted by solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244432/reading-log-files-incrementally-in-java.

Comment: I had no alternative but to read the entire file till I reached the required line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Random Access File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). It lets you access file randomly, and thereby, you can start reading the file, from wherever you need to(not necessarily from the start).

Comment: With this method i'm not able to read it by line and split it, or am i wrong?

Comment: even this has `readLine()` method to read **line by line**. And that line, you can split, as you were doing before.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll give it a try, thanks. Will post if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article: http://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-very-large-file-in-java/, `BufferedReader` has a `skip()` method that could be used to jump into the file (in a seemingly similar way to Random Access File).